# Legitimate IV for panel?

Tags: regression, panel-data, instrumental-variables

In a panel regression using fixed effects, is it correct to use an instrument that does not vary by year?  To use an old but simple example, Angrist and Kruger 1991 use quarter of birth as an instrument for education.  If one had access to similar data that was in panel form, is it still correct (and I don't mean specifically quarter of birth, I know there are problems with the validity of this IV) to use quarter of birth (same for each respondent regardless of panel wave) as an instrument in the panel IV regression?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the instrument does not vary across years, it would be perfectly related to a linear combination of the fixed effects in the model. This would lead to a lack of identification.

In a panel, a better bet would be to employ a difference-in-difference approach, so long as treatment/the endogenous variable is changing across time. The individual fixed effects control for non-time varying unobservable characteristics (*e.g.*, IQ). Year/time period fixed effects control for non-individual varying unobservable characteristics (*e.g.*, the state of the labor market). Any endogeneity problem would stem from time and individual varying omitted variables.

Comment: My endogenous and treatment var's change over time, but my treatment is an ordered variable.  Is it possible to use the DiD method with a non-binary treatment (ie a 'dose' treatment)?  I know I could choose a value of my ordered treatment and generate a 1/0 var, but then I lose information.